# Login into magento from outside of magento without ruining $_SESSION

Tags: magento-1.8, session, login, external

I am trying to integrate an external site with magento, so that when a user logs into site A, magentos session cookie gets set.

Currently I am doing this:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"]; // not the same as magento password

//Validation.... sets that user is logged in in $_SESSION
session_start();
//login writes to $_SESSION
$success = login($username, $password);

if(!$success)die("Wrong credentials");
require_once("/path/to/mysite/magento/app/Mage.php");
Mage::app("default");
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$session->loginById($customer->getId());
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

//User is now logged in, redirect somewhere else
header("Location: home.php");
```

the problem is if I write to the session before magento starts it's magic, magento won't write to its cookie, and if I start magentos session before validation I can no longer write to $_SESSION and have it persist to the next (non-magento) page.

So, is there any way I can log a user into magento from outside magento, and not ruin my session?

Comment: Yes you can creare webservice

Comment: Yes, thank you for elaborating, I know magento has a webservice, but I need the customer to log into magento externally (I.e. without their magento password, just id, they are being athenticated elsewhere)

Comment: `require_once("/path/to/mysite/magento/app/Mage.php")` has a syntax error, is that in your script?

Comment: no, I Forgot the semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I came up with (convoluted as it is) is:

```
session_start();

login($_GET["username"], $_GET["password"]);

//These next few lines make me uneasy, but I can't remove the existing session code for magento
session_write_close(); // Write the data, end session
unset($_SESSION); // unset the session, magento uses isset($_SESSION) to check if it
                  // should start a session
session_name("frontend");// change the session name to frontend

require_once("../pop/app/Mage.php");
Mage::app("default");
Mage::getModel('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($username);
$sess = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$sess->loginById($customer->getId());
$sess->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

I also was playing with having a intermediate `loginToMagento.php` page on the site that would log into magento avoiding starting a session, but that was a gross solution.

I would have gone with @benmarks solution but the existing session code was too ingrained into the site to avoid calling `session_start()` before magento started

Answer (score 4):

Magento unfortunately needs to own the session start. However, there is no reason that you cannot manipulate `$_SESSION` directly as long as you:

1. let Magento start the session first
2. do not manipulate anything under one of Magento's session namespaces (e.g. `$_SESSION['customer']`)

POC:

```
//ensure you are getting error output for debug
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//$email = $_POST["email"];
//$password = $_POST["password"]; // not the same as magento password

require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app("default");

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customer = Mage::  getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

//login writes to $_SESSION
//login($username, $password);

$customer->loadByEmail(/* try with a known email address */);
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$session->loginById($customer->getId());
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

if(!isset($_SESSION['foo'])){
    $_SESSION['foo'] = "I'm in ur session.";
    echo 'No foo yet; refresh!';
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['foo'];
}
```