# Login customber login into the magento website from codeigniter

Tags: login

I have two websites, one is made in codeigniter and second one is in magento both are in same root server.

I want to customer login into the magento website from the codeigniter website.

Using the below code login is success but when I am going on magento website it is asking to login again.

```
     require_once ("../app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

    $customer->loadByEmail($email);

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    $session->loginById($customer->getId());
    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
       echo "success";
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 0):

If both the Magento instance and Codeigniter are not on same the same domain,  the cookie domain at,

"System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management"

Should be set to `.site.com` as just blank will set to the top level domain `site.com` without considering subdomains.

- [What's the correct cookie config for a Magento site split across multiple instances as subdomains?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/whats-the-correct-cookie-config-for-a-magento-site-split-across-multiple-instan)

IF they are NOT on same domain, then you'll need **CORS**:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

---

*Edit*

Take a look at the answer below for a working example, specially `$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);`

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14925/69

Comment: Both the  Magento and Codeigniter are on the same domain

Comment: magento website is just in a folder of same root

Comment: @MaheshKumar updated answer.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the issue in my code.

Comment: After login the magento outside the project a new session file is generated  into the ver/session folder.

Comment: My login session has created  but going on the magento website it is asking again login